# @PicketLink annotated class is not used in identity.login()

Tags: java, jboss, annotations, wildfly-9, picketlink

I'm trying to use an @PicketLinked class that extends the BaseAuthenticator.

My set-up is an ear project on wildfly 9.0.2.Final.

I'm using this in my jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<jboss-deployment-structure>  
<deployment>  
     <dependencies>  
          <!-- This will enable PicketLink Authentication/Authorization and IDM dependencies to your deployment. -->
        <module name="org.picketlink.core.api" meta-inf="import" annotations="true"/>
        <module name="org.picketlink.core" meta-inf="import" annotations="true"/>
        <module name="org.picketlink.idm.api" meta-inf="import" annotations="true"/>
        <module name="org.picketlink.idm" meta-inf="import" annotations="true"/>    
        <module name="org.picketlink.common" meta-inf="import" annotations="true"/>
        <module name="org.picketlink.idm.schema" meta-inf="import" annotations="true"/>
    </dependencies>  
</deployment> 
<sub-deployment name="prestiz-web.war">
    <dependencies>  
          <!-- This will enable PicketLink Authentication/Authorization and IDM dependencies to your deployment. -->
        <module name="org.picketlink.core.api" meta-inf="import" annotations="true"/>
        <module name="org.picketlink.core" meta-inf="import" annotations="true"/>
        <module name="org.picketlink.idm.api" meta-inf="import" annotations="true"/>
        <module name="org.picketlink.idm" meta-inf="import" annotations="true"/>    
        <module name="org.picketlink.common" meta-inf="import" annotations="true"/>
        <module name="org.picketlink.idm.schema" meta-inf="import" annotations="true"/>
    </dependencies> 
</sub-deployment>
<sub-deployment name="prestiz-ejb.jar">
    <dependencies>  
          <!-- This will enable PicketLink Authentication/Authorization and IDM dependencies to your deployment. -->
        <module name="org.picketlink.core.api" meta-inf="import" annotations="true"/>
        <module name="org.picketlink.core" meta-inf="import" annotations="true"/>
        <module name="org.picketlink.idm.api" meta-inf="import" annotations="true"/>
        <module name="org.picketlink.idm" meta-inf="import" annotations="true"/>    
        <module name="org.picketlink.common" meta-inf="import" annotations="true"/>
        <module name="org.picketlink.idm.schema" meta-inf="import" annotations="true"/>
    </dependencies> 
</sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

My BaseAuthenticator class is declared as following within my ejb.jar

```
@RequestScoped
@PicketLink
public class PicketlinkAuthenticator extends BaseAuthenticator
```

My LoginController is configured as following:

```
@Path("/login")
public class LoginController {
    @Inject
    private Identity identity;

    @Inject
    private DefaultLoginCredentials credentials;

    @GET
    @Path("/dologin/{username}/{password}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Transactional(TxType.REQUIRED)
    public String doLogin(@PathParam("username") String username, @PathParam("password") String password){
        credentials.setUserId(username);
        credentials.setPassword(password);
        AuthenticationResult authResult=identity.login();
        if(authResult.equals(AuthenticationResult.SUCCESS)){
            return "success";
        }else{
            return "failed";
        }
    }
```

After identity.login() is called I see this in the logs:

```
11:49:09,630 INFO  [org.picketlink.idm] (default task-2) PLIDM001000:  Bootstrapping PicketLink IDM Partition Manager
11:49:09,667 INFO  [org.picketlink.idm.identity.store] (default task-2) PLIDM001001: Initializing Identity Store [class org.picketlink.idm.file.internal.FileIdentityStore]
11:49:09,679 WARN  [org.picketlink.idm.identity.store.file] (default task-2) PLIDM001101: Working directory [C:\Users\bgadeyne\AppData\Local\Temp\pl-idm] is marked to be always created. All your existing data will be lost.
11:49:09,688 INFO  [org.picketlink.idm.identity.store.file] (default task-2) PLIDM001100: Using working directory [C:\Users\bgadeyne\AppData\Local\Temp\pl-idm].
```

The authenticate method of my authenticator has also some logging but this is not shown.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that you require a AuthenticatorSelector which will select your authenticator. This allows you to have multiple authenticators:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Instance;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import lombok.Setter;
import org.picketlink.annotations.PicketLink;
import org.picketlink.authentication.Authenticator;
import org.picketlink.authentication.internal.IdmAuthenticator;



@RequestScoped
@Named
public class AuthenticatorSelector {
    @Inject private Instance<SingleSignOnAuthenticator> ssoAuthenticator;
    @Inject private Instance<IdmAuthenticator> idmAuthenticator;
    @Inject private Instance<TokenAuthenticator> tokenAuthenticator;

    @Setter private boolean singleSignOn = false; 
    @Setter private boolean tokenAuth = false; 

    public boolean getSingleSignOn() {return singleSignOn;}

    @Produces
    @PicketLink
    public Authenticator selectAuthenticator() {
        if (singleSignOn) {
            return ssoAuthenticator.get();
        } else if (tokenAuth) {
            return tokenAuthenticator.get();
        } else {
            return idmAuthenticator.get();
        }
    }
```